# Unable to set text to a li element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the date and time to a i element present under a class

This is my HTML

This is the way i have tried it .

```
<li class="dateTime">
            <i>
            </i>
         </li>


function displayDate() 
{
    var datetime = getDateTime();
    $('.dateTime').closest('i').text(datetime);
}

function getDateTime() {

   return "30-Jul-2014" ;
}
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qu8E4/2/

please help me how to resolve this ??

Comment: Your fiddle has two functions. What calls them?

Comment: Ya good point i forgot that actually .

Comment: I'm sure you are familiar with CSS selectors. Have you tried `'.dateTime i'` by chance? Have you read the documentation of `.closest()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

see, you are looking for a `descendant` not a `parent`,then why should we need to use `.closest()`.

```
$('.dateTime').find('i').text(datetime);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qu8E4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` selector for decedent element

```
 $('.dateTime').find('i').text(datetime);
       OR 
$('.dateTime i').text(datetime);
```

NOTE: `closest` will select parents(ancestor) only not child

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function getDateTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = now.getDate();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    if (month.toString().length == 1) {
        var month = '0' + month;
    }
    if (day.toString().length == 1) {
        var day = '0' + day;
    }
    if (hour.toString().length == 1) {
        var hour = '0' + hour;
    }
    if (minute.toString().length == 1) {
        var minute = '0' + minute;
    }
    if (second.toString().length == 1) {
        var second = '0' + second;
    }
    var dateTime = year + '/' + month + '/' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
    return dateTime;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
displayDate();
});

function displayDate() 
{
    var datetime = getDateTime();

    $('.dateTime>i').text(datetime);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qu8E4/6/)**